# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 with "_cblas_sgemm", referenced from:

Tags: ios, linker-errors

I encounter a problem that i try my best to resolve it, but i spend so much time it not working for me.

I don't have any idea to fix it. My project build on Xcode 9.1, **libnama.a** library is in a thirdParty for my project,called **Faceunity**, .a library added my project, Other Linker Flags i have added **$(inherited)**

Architectures set *armv7 armv7s arm64 x86_64*, used some other people's methods it always not ok!!!! I hope that if anyone have any idea maybe to fix please tell me, thanks!

**Error:**

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_cblas_sgemm", referenced
>   from:
>         _cnn_run in libnama.a(cnn-arm64.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Other info:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @nickpan, maybe you resolved it? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical error when we integrate third-party libraries in our applications. **It is saying that the required library has not built for arm64 architecture.**

The linker couldn't able to find the symbols for arm64 in the specified static library. To check the supported architectures for static library use **lipo** or **file**

> lipo -info libGoogleAnalytics.a .
>   Architectures in the fat file:libGoogleAnalytics.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64

Answer (score 0):

It is because some third party library includes support simulators. But while building the application you have to exclude the support to the architecture support for simulators

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

Comment: But i always don't how to fix it! can you tell me how to resolved my issue with your suggestion? please speak sample, I want to try. So thanks

Comment: What are you trying to say i am unable to understand. Still as per your problem if you use this script you won't be having this problem. Go to build phase there will be a plus button click on it and select "new run script phase" and in script section just use my script

Comment: I used your methods to add script in Target -> Build Phases -> Run Script , i direct copy your code paste in textBox. But it not work for me, whether i miss do someting? such as exchang ${WRAPPER_NAME} or $FRAMEWORK/Info.plist